# Количество участников сервера в названии канала discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хотел сделать количество участников в названии канала, но код не работает:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(697699362041626644)
    guilds = guild.member_count
    channel = get_channel(761963570799575051)
    await channel.edit(name = f'Учатники: {guilds}')


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(697699362041626644)
    guilds = guild.member_count
    channel = client.get_channel(761963570799575051)
    await channel.edit(name = f'Учатники: {guilds}')
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоль?

Comment: В консоли тишина @xZartsust

Comment: В консоль ничего не выводит